# Are there headshot damage items for all armor slots?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm going for a max damage Infiltrator and I'm wondering if I'm missing some armor?

My current armor setup looks like this:
[image]

But Chest and Legs add `+10% Damage` and i would like to know if there is a `+5% Damage and 10% Headshot Damage` chest and leg armor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no armor component to increase headshot damage for either the Legs or Torso.  The Hahne-Kedar +10% damage is the closest thing.

[Source](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Armor_Customization_%28Mass_Effect_3%29)

Comment: I can't shoot people with my legs or chest?! What's wrong with this world.

Comment: @BenBrocka Yes you can, just not Headshots! :D

Answer (score 2):

This may be of use to you: http://www.gamefront.com/mass-effect-3-best-armor/ I was wondering the same, because I also wanted a high damage infiltrator.

If you want some specific items that boost damage:

Recon Hood 
Kestrel Torso
Strength boost pads (Boosts melee damage by a whopping 25%.) or N7 Shoulder Guards. (3% Wep. damage bonus.) 
Kestrel arm sheathing(3% Weapon damage, 3% shield bonus, 10% melee bonus.) or stabilization gaunlets(5% weapon damage bonus.)

Comment: He's looking for items that 1. boost headshot damage and 2 are for The leg and torso slots

Comment: @CaulynDarr I'm aware. But since those do not exist, I gave him info that would help with the first few words of his question: "I'm going for a max damage Infiltrator" See?

Comment: If you look at the setup he has in the screen shot, you'll notice that the items you suggested would not increase his headshot damage bonus over what he already has equipped.  He has just about the best min/max setup for boosting headshot damage you can get.

Answer (score -1):

I'm sorry, there's no leg or chest armor that'll increase your headshot damage. You'll have to stick to head armor.